# Libreoffice firefox plugin

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, plugins

On Ubuntu 14.10 I have had a libreoffice writer plugin for Firefox. I.I am pretty sure I installed it from Ubuntu's repositories.It opened all documents in read only mode inside of Firefox.

However now I have Ubuntu 15.04 and now I can't find that plugin anywhere.I have tried looking for it in the repositories with synaptic,Google,Firefox's own add on center...

Does anyone perhaps know the exact name of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension in Firefox called [WebODF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webodf/).

> Viewer for OpenDocument Format office files. It can display documents
>   saved from LibreOffice, OpenOffice, Calligra, Abiword, Microsoft Word,
>   Excel, PowerPoint. The documents should be saved in the OpenDocument
>   Format.

**Another Solution**

I think you are talking about the package called `browser-plugin-libreoffice`

It's still available for Ubuntu 15.04 :https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/browser-plugin-libreoffice

Install it and allow the display of LibreOffice documents via a web-browser:

- From any LibreOffice application (Writer,calc..), click on Tools >
  Options.
- Go to Internet > Browser Plug-in.
- In the right pane, check "Display documents in browser".
- Click on OK to validate.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Browser_Plug-in

Comment: Did you really try this? Because according to this https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/gitweb?p=core.git;a=commit;h=496bc3cd6c037360632c33471c4622a095cdcadd it is being deprecated.

Comment: Try the extension of firefox. I tried it